# python-send-string echo begins with print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False) import codecs, os;__pyfile

Tags: python

[OS X 11.6, Emacs 25.1, but also Emacs 24]

In `python-mode` (from `python.el`), any of the commands that use `python-send-string` (e.g., `python-send-region`) print a mess like this at the prompt:

```
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/9l/wcyszrfx3kg7s1sv0bp68_740000j7/T/py201356GE''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/9l/wcyszrfx3kg7s1sv0bp68_740000j7/T/py201356GE''');exec(compile(__code, '''PATH-TO-THE--PYTHONFILE-I-AM-EDITING''', 'exec'));
```

What is this about and how can I stop it?

Comment: Similar report in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25753, still a mystery as to why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem with the message output for every `send-region` command, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726268/emacs-inferior-python-shell-shows-the-send-message-with-each-python-shell-send-r?noredirect=1#comment68473819_33726268). You may wanna invoke `ipython` if you get this problem with python interpreter. Using `ipython` this message no longer appears for me. Put the following in your `.emacs` to start ipython when starting an inferior python shell:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython2")
```

Comment: I don't want to use ipython.

Comment: @MitchellModel According to https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/887#issuecomment-282215656, installing python from "homebrew" could also help.